# Copy Special Cells to next empty row on another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy rows with numbers to another worksheet. I have obtained the SpecialCells code from another forum but have problems pasting the data into another sheet. Thank you for your help!

Here is the code I have:

```
Sub Sample()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim ws1 As Worksheet

On Error GoTo Whoa

Set ws = Sheets("3")
Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")

With ws
    Set rng = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers).EntireRow

    Copy ws1.Range("A" & lastrow)
End With

Exit Sub
End sub
```

Comment: Where is the paste? Where is your `Whoa` error handler? Where is `lastrow` defined/declared?

Comment: @BruceWayne They're not missing a paste action, they're missing the `rng.` which should come before the `Copy` :) The argument after a copy command is the destination, so it should be `rng.Copy ws1.Range("A" & lastrow)`. Your other points stand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
Sub Sample()
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        Sheets("3").UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers).EntireRow.Copy .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    End With
End sub
```

Comment: I tried to use the same code to copy rows of data which are not empty cells. I have removed the "SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)" section but the formula no longer works. the second time i run the macro, the new data is copied into the second data-filled row instead of the next available row.

Comment: This is the code i used to copy data from the Brazil tab into the Tracking Sheet tab

Sub Brazil()
    With Sheets("Tracking Sheet")
        Sheets("Brazil").UsedRange.EntireRow.Copy .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    End With
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

I don;t see anywehre in your code that you defines and set `lastrow`.

Modify your last section to:

```
With ws
    Set Rng = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers).EntireRow

    lastrow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1 ' <-- get the last row in column A '<-- just in case you are looking for the first empty row in Column A 
    Rng.Copy ws1.Range("A" & lastrow) '<-- you need to add the Rng.Copy
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the code below.This will copy data from sheet named "3" to "sheet1".

```
Sub Sample()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim ws1 As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("3")
Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
LastRow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Set rng = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers).EntireRow
rng.Copy
ws1.Activate
Range("A" & LastRow + 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```